# Interpolate a video to 60fps with ffmpeg?

Tags: ffmpeg, video

I want to interpolate a video to 60fps with ffmpeg, How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

The minterpolate filter can do the trick:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -filter:v "minterpolate='mi_mode=mci:mc_mode=aobmc:vsbmc=1:fps=60'" output.mkv
```

Comment: I am always anew amazed at ffmpegs capabilities. Thanks for sharing!